# Getting checkbox values to appear in email with php

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

Hello I'm having trouble getting my checkbox values to show in my email.

I have looked around and tired many different solutions none seem to work.
I created this application for my web site. Please help me solve this issue.

The form does send an email. information does show up just not for the checkboxes.

This is the html code for the form.

```
 <form id="jobapp" name="jobapp" method="post" action="jobappprocess.php">
        <p><span class="h2">Personal Information</span></p>
        <table width="742" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="121" align="right" valign="middle"><label for="firstname">First Name:</label></td>
            <td width="240" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="30" maxlength="35" /></td>
            <td width="106" align="right" valign="middle">Middle Intial:</td>
            <td width="241" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="middleintial" type="text" id="middleintial" size="1" maxlength="1" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Last Name:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="30" maxlength="35" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Social Security 

              Number:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="ssn" type="text" id="ssn" size="13" maxlength="11" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Street Address:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="streetaddress" type="text" id="streetaddress" size="40" maxlength="90" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">City:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="40" maxlength="90" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><label for="zipcode2">Zip Code</label></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="zipcode" type="text" id="zipcode" size="7" maxlength="5" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">State:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="state" type="text" id="state" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><p>Previous Address<br />
            </p></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="previousaddress" type="text" id="previousaddress" size="40" maxlength="90" /></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Home Phone:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="homephone" type="text" id="homephone" size="15" maxlength="13" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Mobile Phone:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="mobilephone" type="text" id="mobilephone" size="15" maxlength="13" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><label for="emailaddress">Email Address</label>
: </td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="emailaddress" type="text" id="emailaddress" size="35" maxlength="40" /></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Are you 18 years of age or older?</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><label>
              <input type="radio" name="areyou18[]" value="Yes" id="areyou18" />
              Yes</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="areyou18[]" value="No" id="areyou18" />
                No</label></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="h2">Position Desired</p>
        <table width="850" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="218" align="right" valign="middle"><label for="positiondesired">What positon are you applying for?</label></td>
            <td width="218" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="positiondesired" type="text" id="positiondesired" size="30" maxlength="30" /></td>
            <td width="228" align="right"><label for="startdate">What date are you available to start?</label></td>
            <td width="150" align="left" valign="middle"><input name="startdate" type="text" id="startdate" size="20" maxlength="10" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Type of Employment:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><p>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="typeofemployment[]" value="Full-time" id="TypeofEmployment_0" />
                Full-time</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="typeofemployment[]" value="Part-time" id="TypeofEmployment_1" />
                Part-time</label>
              <br />
            </p></td>
            <td align="right">Days Available for work:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="sunday[]" id="sunday" />
              <label for="sunday">sun</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="monday[]" id="monday" />
                <label for="monday[]">mon</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tuesday[]" id="tuesday" />
                <label for="tuesday">tue</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="wednesday[]" id="wednesday" />
                <label for="wednesday">wed</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="thursday[]" id="thursday" />
                <label for="thursday">thur</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="friday[]" id="friday" />
                <label for="friday">fri</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="saturday[]" id="saturday" />
                <label for="saturday">sat</label>                
                <br />
              </p></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="h2">Education</p>
        <table width="850" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><label for="highschool">High School:</label></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="highschool" type="text" id="highschool" size="50" maxlength="50" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><label for="hsdatesattended">Dates Attended:</label></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="hsdatesattended" type="text" id="hsdatesattended" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Did you Graduate?</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="hsgraduate[]" value="Yes" id="Graduate_0" />
              Yes</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="hsgraduate[]" value="No" id="Graduate_1" />
                No</label></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><label for="college2">College or University:</label></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="college" type="text" id="college" size="50" maxlength="60" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Dates Attended:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="collegedates" type="text" id="collegedates" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><label for="achievements2">Achievements: List your degrees, certificates, and awards, if any.</label></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><textarea name="achievements" id="achievements" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Did you Graduate?</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="collegegradyes[]" id="yes" />
              <label for="yes">yes<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="collegegradno[]" id="no" />
                no              </label></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle"><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><p><br />
            </p></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Have you served as a member of the U.S. Armed Forces?</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="armedforces[]" value="Yes" id="armedforces" />
              Yes</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="armedForces[]" value="No" id="armedforces" />
                No</label></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Branch/Services:</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="afbranch" type="text" id="afbranch" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            <td align="right" valign="middle">Rank/Speciaty</td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="afrank" type="text" id="afrank" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="h2"> Work Experience</p>
        <table width="850" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="99" align="right"><label for="presentlastemployer">Present or Last Employer:</label></td>
            <td width="287" align="left"><input name="presentlastemployer" type="text" id="presentlastemployer" size="40" maxlength="30" /></td>
            <td width="127" align="right"><label for="plphone">Telephone:</label></td>
            <td width="150" align="left"><input name="plphone" type="text" id="plphone" size="15" maxlength="13" /> </td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="pladdress">Street Address:</label></td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pladdress" type="text" id="pladdress" size="40" maxlength="90" /></td>
            <td align="right"><label for="plcity">City:</label></td>
            <td align="left"><input name="plcity" type="text" id="plcity" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">State:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="plstate" type="text" id="plstate" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
            <td align="right">Zip Code:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="plzipcode" type="text" id="plzipcode" size="7" maxlength="5" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Position Held:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="plposition" type="text" id="plposition" size="30" maxlength="30" /></td>
            <td align="right">Dates of Employment:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pldates" type="text" id="pldates" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Job Description:</td>
            <td align="left"><textarea name="pldescription" id="pldescription" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            <td align="right">Supervisor:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="plsupervisor" type="text" id="plsupervisor" size="40" maxlength="35" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Reason for Leaving:</td>
            <td align="left"><p>
              <textarea name="plreasonforleaving" id="plreasonforleaving" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
              <br />
            </p></td>
            <td align="right">Salary:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="plsalary" type="text" id="plsalary" size="20" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">May we contact your present employer?</td>
            <td align="left"><label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="plmaywecontact[]" value="Yes" id="plmaywecontact" />
              Yes</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="plmaywecontact[]" value="No" id="plmaywecontact" />
                No</label></td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center" class="h2"> More Work Experience</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Previous Employer:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="previousemployer" type="text" id="previousemployer" size="40" maxlength="30" /></td>
            <td align="right">Telephone:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pephone" type="text" id="pephone" size="15" maxlength="13" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><label for="peaddress2">Address:</label></td>
            <td align="left"><input name="peaddress" type="text" id="peaddress" size="40" maxlength="50" /></td>
            <td align="right">City:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pecity" type="text" id="pecity" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">State:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pestate" type="text" id="pestate" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td>
            <td align="right">Zip Code:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pezipcode" type="text" id="pezipcode" size="7" maxlength="5" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Position Held:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="peposition" type="text" id="peposition" size="30" maxlength="20" /></td>
            <td align="right">Dates of Employment:</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pedates" type="text" id="pedates" size="30" maxlength="25" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right">Job description:</td>
            <td align="left"><textarea name="pedescription" id="pedescription" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            <td align="right">Supervisor</td>
            <td align="left"><input name="pesupervisor" type="text" id="pesupervisor" size="35" maxlength="30" /></td>
            </tr>
          <tr class="agree">
            <td align="right">Reason for leaving:</td>
            <td align="center" class="agree"><textarea name="peresasonforleaving" id="peresasonforleaving" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
            <td align="right" class="agree">Salary:</td>
            <td align="left" class="agree"><input type="text" name="pesalary" id="pesalary" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><span class="agree"></span></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="362" align="center"><span class="h2">Do you accept the terms of this application?</span></td>
            <td width="120"><span class="h2">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="acceptterms[]" value="Yes" id="AcceptTermsofapplication_0" />
                Yes</label>
              <br />
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="acceptterms[]" value="No" id="AcceptTermsofapplication_1" />
                No</label>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submitapp" type="submit" id="Submit Application" onclick="MM_validateForm('firstname','','R','lastname','','R','ssn','','RisNum','streetaddress','','R','city','','R','zipcode','','RisNum','state','','R','homephone','','RisNum','mobilephone','','RisNum','emailaddress','','RisEmail','positiondesired','','R','startdate','','RisNum','highschool','','R','presentlastemployer','','R','pladdress','','R','plstate','','R','plposition','','R','pldates','','R','plsupervisor','','R','plsalary','','NisNum','pephone','','NisNum','pezipcode','','NisNum','pedates','','NisNum','pesalary','','NisNum','pldescription','','R','plreasonforleaving','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit Application" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="h2">&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="h2">&nbsp;</p>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the php code

```
<?php

foreach ($_SESSION['Checkbox'] as $val) {
$checkboxresults .= $val.",\n";
}

echo (is_array($_REQUEST['$checkbox']) ? implode("\n", $_REQUEST['$checkbox']) : $_REQUEST['$checkbox']);


/* Subject and Email Variables */

    $emailSubject = 'New Job Appilcant!';
    $webMaster = '';
    $from = 'emailaddressField';



/* Gathering Data Variables */



    $firstnameField = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastnameField = $_POST['lastname'];
    $middleintialField = $_POST['middleintial'];
    $streetaddressField = $_POST['streetaddress'];
    $cityField = $_POST['city'];
    $stateField = $_POST['state'];
    $zipcodeField = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $ssnField = $_POST['ssn'];
    $previousaddressField = $_POST['previousaddress'];
    $homephoneField = $_POST['homephone'];
    $mobilephoneField = $_POST['mobilephone'];
    $emailaddressField = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    $areyou18Field = $_POST['areyou18'];
    $positiondesiredField = $_POST['positiondesired'];
    $startdateField = $_POST['startdate'];
    $typeofemploymentField = $_POST['typeofemployment'];
    $sundayField = $_POST ['sunday'];
    $mondayField = $_POST ['monday'];
    $tuesdayField = $_POST ['tuesday'];
    $wednesdayField = $_POST ['wednesday'];
    $thursdayField = $_POST ['thursday'];
    $fridayField = $_POST ['friday'];
    $saturdayField = $_POST ['saturday'];
    $highschoolField = $_POST['highschool'];
    $hsdatesattendedField = $_POST['hsdatesattended'];
    $hsgraduateField = $_POST['hsgraduate'];
    $collegeField = $_POST['college'];
    $collegedatesField = $_POST['collegedates'];
    $collegegradyesField = $_POST['collegegradyes'];
    $collegegradnoField = $_POST['collegegradno'];
    $achievementsField = $_POST['achievements'];
    $armedforcesField = $_POST['armedforces'];
    $afbranchField = $_POST['afbranch'];
    $afrankField = $_POST['afrank'];
    $previouslastemployerField = $_POST['previouslastemployer'];
    $plphoneField = $_POST['plphone'];
    $pldatesField = $_POST['pldates'];
    $pladdressField = $_POST['pladdress'];
    $plcityField = $_POST['plcity'];
    $plstateField = $_POST['plstate'];
    $plzipcodeField = $_POST['plzipcode'];
    $plsupervisorField = $_POST['plsupervisor'];
    $plpositionField = $_POST['plposition'];
    $pldescriptionField = $_POST['pldescription'];
    $plsalaryField = $_POST['plsalary'];
    $plreasonforleavingField = $_POST['plreasonforleaving'];
    $maywecontactField = $_POST['maywecontact'];
    $previousemployerField = $_POST['previousemployer'];
    $pephoneField = $_POST['pephone'];
    $pedatesField = $_POST['pedates'];
    $peaddressField = $_POST['peaddress'];
    $pecityField = $_POST['pecity'];
    $pestateField = $_POST['pestate'];
    $pezipcodeField = $_POST['pezipcode'];
    $pesupervisorField = $_POST['pesupervisor'];
    $pepositionField = $_POST['peposition'];
    $pedescriptionField = $_POST['pedescription'];
    $pesalaryField = $_POST['pesalary'];
    $pereasonforleavingField = $_POST['acceptterms'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
<p>
Name: $firstnameField $middleintialField $lastnameField <br><br>
Address: $streetaddressField $cityField $stateField $zipcodeField <br><br>
SSN: $ssnField <br><br>
Previous Address: $previousaddressField <br><br>
Home Phone: $homephoneField <br><br>
Mobile Phone: $mobilephoneField <br><br>
Email: $emailaddressField <br><br>
Eight-teen Plus: $areyou18Field <br><br>
Position Desired: $positiondesiredField <br><br>
Date available to start: $startdateField <br><br>
Type of Employment: $typeofemploymentField <br><br>
Days available to work: $sundayField, $mondayField, $tuesdayField, $wednesdayField, $thursdayField, $fridayField, $saturdayField 
<br><hr><br>
High School: $highschoolField, $hsdatesattenedField, $hsgraduateField 
<br><hr><br>
College: $collegeField, $collegedatesField, $collegegradyesField, $collegegradnoField, $achievements
<br><hr><br>
Armed Forces: $armedforcesField, $afbranchField, $afrankField  
<br><hr><br>
Recent Employer <br>
<p>
$presentlastemployerField
$plphoneField
$pldatesField
$pladdressField
$plcityField
$plstateField
$plzipcodeField
$supervisorField
$plpositionField
$pldescriptionField
$plsalaryField
$plreasonforleavingField
$plmaywecontactField</p> 
<br><hr><br>
Previous Employer <br>
<p>
$previousemployerField
$pephoneField
$pedatesField
$peaddressField
$pecityField
$pestateField
$pezipcodeField
$pesupervisorField
$pepositionField
$pedescriptionField
$pesalaryField
$pereasonforleavingField</p> 
<br><hr><br>
Accept Terms of Employment <br><br>
$accepttermsField
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $emailaddressField\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail ($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);


?>
```

As I said the the form does submit. The check box values don't appear.
Thank you for in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add 'value' attribute to the each checkbox input. I noticed that you forgot to do it for "Days Available for work" checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you that did help. Its still some errors, but that's got me in the right direction. Thank you again.